# Execution failed for task ':@react-native-community_datetimepicker:generateDebugRFile'

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, build.gradle

[The result when i try to run 'react-native run-android'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnPlH.png).

This is my android/build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "+"
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Hello guys! Recently I started to work on a new  React-Native project. I cloned the repository, installed the node modules and tried to run the project by running the following commands :

1. git clone
2. npm install
3. react-native start
4. react-native run-android ( in a second terminal)

I should mention that the last person who worked on that project said that it had no errors last time he checked. (that was 3 months ago).
I think it has something to do with android/build.gradle configuration. Maybe some dependencies paths were changed ?

Answer (score 0):

go to android folder and inside terminal run this command:

```
gradlew clean
```

it also can be a network problem.
I suggest you to upgrade your react-native to latest version with the help of [this](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/) link

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your reply! I already tried gradlew clean and I have the same error. Do you think upgrading the react-native version will help?

Comment: yes I highly recommend to upgrade your react native to the latest version